# Using R with API Key

Tags: r, json, api, web-scraping

I am subscribing to ORATS(an options data provider) API. Here is an example they use to extract data.
[image]

Here is an example they provide on their website. I have to use the api_key with every pull. How would I structure this in a GET() command? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Include a call to `add_headers()` to add the necessary header:

```
token <- "your-token-here"
GET("https://api.orats.io/data/summaries?ticker=AAPL",
    add_headers(Authorization=token))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you would do something like:

```
url <- "https://api.orats.io/data/summaries?ticker=AAPL"
api_key <- "your-private-token"
res <- GET(url=url, add_headers('Authorization' = paste("Authorization: ", api_key)))
```

Comment: Hey cgrafe, thanks for your response however this this did not work. The above answered worked.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes they want the text explicitly in the header.